# [Django]django.db.utils.IntegrityError

Tags: python, django, django-models

my app named mainsite

I have the table class named Weather in models.py

```
class Weather(models.Model):
    tpr = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    wet = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    ur = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    li = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    observe_time = models.DateTimeField(default=None)
```

I don't want my `observe_time` set any deafult value

So I set to None .

I have made migrations.

when I made migrate

Then the traceback happen:

> File "manage.py", line 22, in 
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
>
> File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>
> line 354, in execute_from_command_line
>
> ```
> utility.execute()   File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",
> ```
>
> line 346, in execute
>
> ```
> self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
> ```
>
> line 394, in run_from_argv
>
> ```
> self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
> ```
>
> line 445, in execute
>
> ```
> output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py",
> ```
>
> line 222, in handle
>
> ```
> executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)   File
> ```
>
> "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py",
>
> line 110, in migrate
>
> ```
> self.apply_migration(states[migration], migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)   File
> ```
>
> "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py",
>
> line 148, in apply_migration
>
> ```
> state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)   File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py",
> ```
>
> line 115, in apply
>
> ```
> operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)   File
> ```
>
> "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py",
>
> line 62, in database_forwards
>
> ```
> field,   File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py",
> ```
>
> line 179, in add_field
>
> ```
> self._remake_table(model, create_fields=[field])   File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py",
> ```
>
> line 147, in _remake_table
>
> ```
> self.quote_name(model._meta.db_table),   File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py",
> ```
>
> line 111, in execute
>
> ```
> cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
> ```
>
> line 79, in execute
>
> ```
> return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
> ```
>
> line 64, in execute
>
> ```
> return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line
> ```
>
> 98, in **exit**
>
> ```
> six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)   File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line
> ```
>
> 685, in reraise
>
> ```
> raise value.with_traceback(tb)   File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
> ```
>
> line 64, in execute
>
> ```
> return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py",
> ```
>
> line 318, in execute
>
> ```
> return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params) django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed:
> ```
>
> mainsite_weather__new.observe_time

I don't know what caused this error.

thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for this to work you should also make this field nullable and blankable, like this:

```
observe_time = models.DateTimeField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
```

or omit `default=None` completely, like this:

```
observe_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Also, after that, don't forget to delete the previous migration file and run `makemigrations` and `migrate` again.